# How to use an if/else statement to create a new column in SAS?

Tags: sas

In SAS I want to create a new column based on some simple logic.  My code is as follows:

```
data MyTable2;
set MyTable1;
if end_dt < 10/31/2021
then Letter_Send_dt = INTX('Month',end_dt,-2,'end')
else Letter_Send_dt = INTX('Month',end_dt,-3,'end');
format Letter_Send_dt yymmdd10.;
run;
```

I know my syntax must be wrong but I've searched and can't figure out what the correct syntax should look like. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- date constant specified incorrectly
- missing semicolon

```
data MyTable2;
set MyTable1;

if end_dt < "31Oct2021"d then Letter_Send_dt = INTX('Month',end_dt,-2,'end');
else Letter_Send_dt = INTX('Month',end_dt,-3,'end');

format Letter_Send_dt yymmdd10.;

run;
```

Comment: That did it! I'll accept this answer in 5 minutes when it allows me to.  Thank you